# How to add responsive height or width of the image to the container?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, height, responsive

`<div style={{height: ? }}>`
`<img style={{height: 'auto'}} src=""/>`
`</div>`

I need to know, how to access the height value even if it's changed in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Add This type of css for responsive image using object-fit.

```css
.image-container{

  width: 33.3333%;
  
}

img{
  
  width:100%;
  height: 400px;   //this height according to you
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the element has been rendered in the DOM, one way you could access it’s actual, rendered height would be using `getComputedStyle` ([MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)).

Here’s an example of how that can be used:

```
const img = document.querySelector('div img');
const styles = window.getComputedStyle(img);
console.log('height:', styles.getPropertyValue('height'));
```

Does that help?